# javascript why "document.documentElement.childNodes" output different result?

Tags: javascript, dom, document

I think "document.documentElement.cildNodes" is all childnodes in tag  as before,but today I do my code excrise, I find a special case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript</title>
<script>
    var o = document.createElement('script');
    o.text = 'alert("111")';
    var ohtml = document.documentElement;
    alert(ohtml.nodeName); //output HTML
        alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); //nodes length is 1
    alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); //just head
    ohtml.childNodes[0].appendChild(o);
    function shownode() {
        var ohtml = document.documentElement;
        alert(ohtml.nodeName);
        alert(ohtml.childNodes.length);  //nodes length is 3
        alert(ohtml.childNodes[0].nodeName); //head 
        alert(ohtml.childNodes[1].nodeName); //#text 
                alert(ohtml.childNodes[2].nodeName); //body 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body><div>test</div><input id="Button1" type="button" value="show nodes" onclick="shownode();" />
</body>
</html>
```

why I excute "document.documentElement.childNodes" in tag  and function in tag  will get different result?
I hope someone can give me more exsample about this.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is, you do it in a head script tag so when it gets executed, the whole DOM hasn't been loaded in the page, yet. And when you call the function for instance in the console, the DOM is loaded completely, to make sure of that you can move all your code to a **`window.onload`** event, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var o = document.createElement('script');
    o.text = 'alert("111")';
    var ohtml = document.documentElement;
    alert(ohtml.nodeName); //output HTML
    alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); //nodes length is not 1
    alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); // not just head
    ohtml.childNodes[0].appendChild(o);
});
```

and if you don't want to use **`window.onload`** event, simply put it inside your body tag:

```
<body>
<!--your stuff-->
<script>
    alert(ohtml.nodeName); //output HTML
    alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); //nodes length is not 1
    alert(ohtml.childNodes.length); // not just head
</script>
</body>
```